# i am not able to install mod_wsgi in windows

Tags: python

```
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Downloading mod_wsgi-4.9.4.tar.gz (497 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 497.5/497.5 kB 46.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mod_wsgi
  Building wheel for mod_wsgi (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi
      copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server\management
      copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server\management
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\docs
      copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\docs
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\images
      copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\images
      copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\mod_wsgi\images
      running build_ext
      building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src\server
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\xampp\apache/include -Ic:\users\91915\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\91915\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
      mod_wsgi.c
      C:\Users\91915\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8p707y44\mod-wsgi_03760927e1fe4d73a104f496ddd3278c\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(39): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ws2tcpip.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod_wsgi
  Running setup.py clean for mod_wsgi
Failed to build mod_wsgi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mod_wsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

i tried by changing the versions of python and mod_wsgi but it is not resolved .....

Comment: First you need to do this `py -m pip install --no-deps mod_wsgi --upgrade`

Comment: it was also not working. i am getting the same error